# How to get rendered javascript source using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I want to get the rendered html source for a page largely consisting of javascript. Is there anyway for me to get this using NSURLConnection? If so how would I frame the request?

The reason for this is I need to parse some of the data on the page - but I do not have to actually display the page itself; which is why I do not want to use a UIWebView.

**UPDATE**

So what I am doing is creating an app for a band. The band already has a website (powered by BandZoogle) which has the tour dates listed on the site. They want me to parse the site and just update the app based on those tour dates. However, BandZoogle is entirely javascript - so I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force Server to execute JavaScript - it can be executed only on client side. But you can use Node.JS for that.

Or, you could use php and then echo to get the executed request.

There is also Meteor Framework, that let's you write your server side on JavaScript.
http://meteor.com/main

Comment: I can't try that now but it should be the same data as what I am getting now. For testing purposes I am using nsurlconnection synchronously and the returned data as a string is just the JavaScript source what I want is the HTML that is rendered by the JavaScript.

Comment: So,you want the JavaScript to make it's work first and the to get all the HTML?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking to accomplish.

Comment: So there's my answer,but is ts kinda hard to implement,really.

Comment: Hello Nikita, sorry for taking so long but your selected approach will not work.